# I created and run a sqlserver container, I stop it and I don't know how to run it again?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I created and run a SQL Server docker container. I stop it and I don't know how to start it again.

I use this command line:

> sudo docker run --name sql_server_db -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=TEST_XXXXXXX' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

Comment: `docker start <image_name>` did not work for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's worked. I am a newbie on docker :)

Comment: You're welcome, I've posted it as an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following command to start the image, where <container_name> is the name of the image:

```
docker start <container_name>
```

Comment: A minor issue here is that you `docker start` an already created container, not an image. To avoid confusion, I would change `<image_name>` to `<container_name>`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction @tgogos, indeed, we're starting a container not an image.